# How to repeat over all characters in a string?

Tags: macros, loops, strings

I have a command that formats a single character, let's call it `\d{}`.  (In my case, \d{} adds a dot under a Chinese character, as this is the custom to emphasize Chinese texts).

I want to define a new command `\ds{}` such that it applies `\d{}` over every letter of the string.

For example `\ds{abc}` would be equivalent to `\d{a}\d{b}\d{c}`.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you expect just characters in the string? Can you give a hint about what `\d` should do? Is this for LaTeX or Plain?

Comment: Yes, there will just be characters in the string.  Not equations.  (But my `\d{}` uses Latex maths inside it, if that matters).

Comment: Can you give us the `\d` definition?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\d}[1]{$\underaccent{\scalebox{0.5}{\textbullet}}{\textrm{#1}}$}`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `\@tfor`. I provide also a better redefinition of the dot under according to your wish:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\let\d\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\d}[1]{%
  \oalign{#1\cr\hidewidth\scalebox{0.5}{\textbullet}\hidewidth\cr}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ds}[1]{%
  \@tfor\next:=#1\do{\d{\next}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

x\d{d}\d{s}\d{a}x

x\ds{dsa}x

\end{document}
```

[image]

What does `\@tfor` do? Its syntax is

```
\@tfor<scratch macro>:=<tokens>\do{<code>}
```

The scratch macro is traditionally `\next`, but it can be anything. The `<tokens>` part is any (brace balanced) list of tokens. In the loop, LaTeX essentially does `\def<scratch macro>{<next token>}`, so

```
\@tfor\next:=dsa\do{\d{\next}}
```

will perform

```
\def\next{d}\d{\next}\def\next{s}\d{\next}\def\next{a}\d{\next}
```

However, with `\@tfor\next:=d {sa}\do{\d{\next}}` we will just obtain

```
\def\next{d}\d{\next}\def\next{sa}\d{\next}
```

Explicit space tokens are ignored and braced groups of tokens are treated as one.

The `expl3` analog is `\tl_map_inline:nn`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\let\d\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\d}[1]{%
  \oalign{#1\cr\hidewidth\scalebox{0.5}{\textbullet}\hidewidth\cr}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ds}{m}
 {
  \tl_map_inline:n { #1 } { \d { ##1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

x\d{d}\d{s}\d{a}x

x\ds{dsa}x

x\ds{d sa{bc}}x

\end{document}
```

No scratch macro is used: the current item in the loop is denoted by `#1` (which becomes `##1` in the body of a definition, as usual).

In this particular case where just a single command is applied with the current item as argument, one can use `\tl_map_function:nN`:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand{\ds}{m}
 {
  \tl_map_function:n { #1 } \d
 }
```

which has the same effect and is shorter. It can also appear in a full expansion context (not for this particular case, because of `\d`).

[image]

Comment: It would be great to have an explanation of `\@tfor`, especially since it's not defined in plain TeX

Answer (score 8):

This solution allows word wrap and handles spaces between words.  In addition, the `[w]` option allows the task to be performed on each word, rather than each character.'

In the MWE, I demonstrate with variously defined tasks:

1. overstrike each character (2 different settings)
2. place a dot under each character
3. place a semicolon under each word
4. apply extra intercharacter space
5. apply extra interword space.

The task is defined in `\charop{}` for characters and `\wordop{}` for words, while the `\chariterate[]{}` macro does the iteration.  Here is the MWE:

```
% WHILE THIS EXAMPLE IS SET UP FOR BOLDING A CALLIGRAPHIC FONT
% ITS GENERAL USE IS TO DO SOMETHING ON EACH char OF ITS ARGUMENT, ALLOWING LINE WRAP
% THE [W] OPTION TO \chariterate DOES SOMETHING TO EACH WORD.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,BCOR10mm,DIV11,toc=listof,parskip=full, openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\chariterate[2][c]{\if w#1\worditeratehelper#2 \relax\relax\else
  \chariteratehelpA#2 \relax\relax\fi}
\def\chariteratehelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \chariteratehelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \chariteratehelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\chariteratehelpB#1#2\relax{%
  \charop{#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \chariteratehelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
\def\worditeratehelper#1 #2\relax{%
  \wordop{#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \worditeratehelper#2\relax\fi
}
\def\charop#1{#1}
\def\wordop#1{#1}
% THIS EXAMPLE ARTIFICIALLY BOLDS EACH char WITH A SHIFTED OVERSTRIKE
\def\charopA{%
  %\def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \def\stacktype{L}%
  \def\stackalignment{l}%
  \def\calup{.2pt}%
  \def\calover{.15pt}%
  \renewcommand\charop[1]{\stackon[\calup]{##1}{\kern\calover##1}}%
}
% HERE'S AN EXAMPLE PLACING DOT UNDER EACH char
\def\charopB{%
  \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \def\stacktype{L}%
  \def\stackalignment{c}%
  \renewcommand\charop[1]{\stackunder[3pt]{##1}{.}}%
}
% EXTRA INTER-CHARACTER SPACE
\def\charopC{\renewcommand\charop[1]{##1\,}}
% HERE'S AN EXAMPLE PLACING DOT UNDER EACH WORD
\def\wordopA{%
  \renewcommand\wordop[1]{\def\stackalignment{c}\stackunder[3pt]{##1}{;}}
}
% EXTRA INTER-WORD SPACE
\def\wordopB{\renewcommand\wordop[1]{##1\ \ }}
%
\newenvironment{calligraphic}%
{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{pzc}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{it}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont}{}%
\renewcommand*{\sectfont}{\normalcolor\usefont{T1}{pzc}{m}{it}}
\begin{document}
\charopA
   \begin{calligraphic}
   Test \textbf{this is not bold}\par
   Test \chariterate{this is bold with .2pt up shift and .15pt right shift}\par
 \def\calup{.0pt}
 \def\calover{.2pt}
   Test \chariterate{this is bold with .0pt up shift and .2pt right shift}\par
   \chariterate{cvxc This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. 
    This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a 
    test. This is a test. This is a test. This fdsfsd is a test. This is a test. 
    This is a test. This is a test. This is adfsdf  test. This is a test.}\par
   \end{calligraphic}\par
\charopB
\wordopA
   \chariterate{This is doing something to each character.}\par
   \chariterate[w]{This is doing something to each word.}\par
   \chariterate{Ich bin m{\"u}de}.  
   \chariterate[w]{Ich bin m{\"u}de}.\par
\charopC
\wordopB
   \chariterate{This is doing something to each character.}\par
   \chariterate[w]{This is doing something to each word.}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the most simple incarnation, to do merely underdots on characters alone, the code can be greatly reduced:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\chariterate[2][c]{\if w#1\worditeratehelper#2 \relax\relax\else
  \chariteratehelpA#2 \relax\relax\fi}
\def\chariteratehelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \chariteratehelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \chariteratehelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\chariteratehelpB#1#2\relax{%
  \charop{#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \chariteratehelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
\def\worditeratehelper#1 #2\relax{%
  \wordop{#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \worditeratehelper#2\relax\fi
}
  \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \def\stacktype{L}%
  \def\stackalignment{c}%
  \newcommand\charop[1]{\stackunder[3pt]{#1}{.}}%
  \def\wordop#1{#1}
\begin{document}
\chariterate{This is doing something to each character.
This is doing something to each character.
This is doing something to each character.}\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that may be useful for Chinese fonts also, when they don't provide the bold fonts.

Comment: Extremely useful! To ensure that also bigger fontsizes like headings look good, I'd suggest to define the length for `\stackunder` in `ex` though.

Answer (score 3):

The question is well suited for my new `tokcycle` package, so I just had to add another answer.  The nice thing here, is that it can apply the underdot even as text style changes and macros are invoked.  The `\underdot` is applied only to printable cat-11 tokens.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\underdot[1]{\ooalign{#1\cr\hfil{\raisebox{-2.5pt}{.}}\hfil}}
\tokcycleenvironment\ds
  {\tctestifcatnx A##1{\addcytoks{\underdot{##1}}}{\addcytoks{##1}}}% CHARACTER DIRECTIVE
  {\processtoks{##1}}% GROUP-CONTENT DIRECTIVE
  {\addcytoks{##1}}% MACRO DIRECTIVE
  {\addcytoks{##1}}% SPACE DIRECTIVE
\begin{document}
\ds abc\endds

\ds This can work \textbf{across \bgroup\itshape changes in text
  style\egroup, and can |escape text, for example $y=2x+1$| and pick
  up where it left off}.  However, only catcode-11 tokens are underdotted.

It can continue across paragraphs.

This is from the new \textsf{tokcycle} package released on 2019/8/21.
\endds

\end{document}
```

[image]