# Spreading letters evenly across a line from margin to margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-spacing

I wish to achieve something that can be easily accomplished by simply pressing this button in Microsoft Word:

[image: Distributed Text Alignment in MS Word]

So that I could make something like this:

[image: Sample title]

What I've seen so far [on this forum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50508/fully-stretch-text-horizontally-on-page) either spreads words instead of letters across the page, or statically define the spacing between letters using `sodef` from the `soul` package to mimic such effect instead of truly stretch the text to reach both ends.

I wonder if there is a single command in LaTeX that could achieve what that button can in Word.

Answer (score 2):

Replace spaces by `{}` (so a double space will appear) and put a space after each letter.

*Caveat* Accented letters won't work. For that much more work is needed unless you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\widen}{mm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ } { {} }
  \noindent
  \makebox[\textwidth][s]
   {
    \skip_set:Nn \spaceskip { 0pt plus 1fill }
    #1 \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 ~ } \unskip
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mytext}{SOMETHING BIG}

\begin{document}

\widen{\huge}{SOMETHING BIG}

\bigskip

\widen{\large}{\mytext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

***Final note:*** *the fact that something is easy with word processors and difficult with TeX is usually a clear sign that it's something rather dubious from the typographer's point of view.*

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using LaTeX's `\makebox` with a `s`tretched alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

\sffamily
\makebox[\linewidth][s]{\LARGE\bfseries S O M E T H I N G {} B I G}

\makebox[\linewidth][s]{s o m e t h i n g {} s m a l l}


\bigskip

\newlength{\somethingbig}
\settowidth{\somethingbig}{\LARGE\bfseries SOMETHING BIG}

{\LARGE\bfseries SOMETHING BIG}

\makebox[\somethingbig][s]{s o m e t h i n g {} s m a l l}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah I see your point. You split each word into letters so that what used to be spreading words across the line would now be spreading letters. Very smart! However, what I put in "something small" is a actually a macro that contains some string data collected from the user in the preamble of the document (a subtitle of some sort). If I am to go with this solution, I will have to write the subtitle as "s u b t i t l e", which is something I wish to avoid. Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution with lualatex using directlua:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Rockwell Extra Bold}

\newcommand\distributed[1]{%
  \makebox[\linewidth][s]{%
    \directlua{
      letters = {}
      for letter in string.gmatch("#1", ".") do
        if letter == " " then
          table.insert(letters, "{}")
        else
          table.insert(letters, letter)
        end
      end
      tex.sprint(table.concat(letters, " "))
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
  \noindent{\Huge\bfseries\distributed{Hello World}}
  \distributed{Some more text}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Adapting my answer at [How to repeat over all characters in a string?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253203/how-to-repeat-over-all-characters-in-a-string/253212#253212).  I had to modify it to not do the added `\hfill` prior to the first character.

As Werner points out, this approach cannot in general accept a macro as part of its argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\chariterate[1]{\chariteratehelpX#1 \relax\relax}
\def\chariteratehelpX#1#2\relax\relax{#1\chariteratehelpA#2\relax\relax}
\def\chariteratehelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \chariteratehelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\hfill\chariteratehelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\chariteratehelpB#1#2\relax{%
  \charop{#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \chariteratehelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
\def\charop#1{\hfill#1}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\noindent{\Huge\chariterate{SOMETHING BIG}}

\noindent{\scriptsize\chariterate{something small}}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about accepting a macro as an argument to `\chariterate`?

Comment: @Werner In general, that will not work.  I should add that as a proviso.