# Spread letters along a certain distance

Tags: letterspacing

I'm aware of `\makebox[*length*][s]{t e x t}`, but I have to put spaces between each character. If I have a pretty long text it feels uncomfortable.

I've seen [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253988/213149) by **egreg** and it works almost like I want. I'd like to specify the length as a first argument and pass the text without separating each letter individually as a second argument using xparse.

```
\spread{20em}{distribute this text}
\spread{5em}{word}
```

But, unfortunately, I was not managed to modify the code to make it work like I want. Could you help me with that?

Comment: So, specifying the inter-letter spacing is not good enough?  You need to be able to specify the overall-length?  If so, you know that will preclude line wrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a simple solution that yields one space between letters and two between words:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\spreadtext}{mm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ } { {} }
  \makebox[#1][s]
   {
    \skip_set:Nn \spaceskip { 0pt plus 1fill }
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 ~ } \unskip
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\spreadtext{20em}{distribute this text}

\spreadtext{5em}{word}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A slightly different one that has more space between words.

You can first split the input at spaces, then split each word at letters. Finally, typeset everything inserting a space between letters and a larger space between words.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\spreadtext}{mm}
 {
  \antshar_spread_text:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__antshar_spread_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__antshar_spread_out_seq
\seq_new:N \l__antshar_spread_word_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \antshar_spread_text:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__antshar_spread_in_seq { ~ } { #2 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__antshar_spread_out_seq \l__antshar_spread_in_seq { \antshar_spread_word:n { ##1 } }
  \makebox[#1][s]
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \l__antshar_spread_out_seq { \hspace{1em plus 0.5em minus 0.3em} }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \antshar_spread_word:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__antshar_spread_word_seq { } { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__antshar_spread_word_seq { ~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\spreadtext{20em}{distribute this text}

\spreadtext{5em}{word}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A version that also copes with commands in the argument.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\spreadtext}{mm}
 {
  \antshar_spreadtext:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_antshar_spreadtext_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__antshar_spreadtext_space:
 {
  \hspace{1em~plus~0.5em~minus~0.3em}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \antshar_spreadtext:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_antshar_spreadtext_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \s } { \c{__antshar_spreadtext_space:} } \l_antshar_spreadtext_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\w) } { \1 \  } \l_antshar_spreadtext_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \s(\c{.*}) } { \1  } \l_antshar_spreadtext_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_antshar_spreadtext_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\spreadtext{20em}{distribute \emph{this} text}

\spreadtext{5em}{word}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without packages, but no command allowed:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\spreadtext}[2]{%
  \makebox[#1][s]{\spread@text#2\spread@text}%
}
\def\spread@text{\futurelet\next\spread@@text}
\def\spread@@text{%
  \ifx\next\spread@text
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\unskip\@gobble}%
  {\spread@@@text}%
}
\def\spread@@@text{%
  \ifx\next\@sptoken
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\spread@space}%
  {\spread@char}%
}
\def\spread@space#1{%
  \hspace{1em plus 0.5em minus 0.3em}%
  \spread@text#1%
}
\def\spread@char#1{#1 \spread@text}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\spreadtext{20em}{distribute this text}

\spreadtext{5em}{word}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I wonder whether it is possible make the xparse code more compact? Your answer about spreadign across the whole like looks way more shorter.

Comment: @antshar Not sure what answer you're referring to.

Comment: There is a hyperlink in the post to your answer. Here it is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253988/213149

Comment: @antshar Oh, that one! I added it.

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much!

Comment: The third approach with regex doesn't seem to be adjustable. At least, it doesn't make use of `#1` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tokcycle`, I provide two forms.  In the first, the intercharacter spacing is specified.  This is provided in the package example documentation.  In the 2nd approach, using the syntax preferred by the OP, the user specifies the overall width of the string.  Note that the target argument can contain formatting macros that are fully honored by `\spread`.

The disadvantage of `\spread` relative to `\spaceouttext` is that the former will not linebreak, whereas the latter will.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\spaceouttext[2]{%
  \tokcycle{\addcytoks{##1\nobreak\hspace{#1}}}%
  {\processtoks{##1}}{\addcytoks{##1}}%
  {\addcytoks{##1\hspace{#1}}}{#2}%
  \the\cytoks\unskip}
\newcommand\spread[2]{%
  \tokcycle
  {\addcytoks{##1\hfill}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1\hfill}}{#2}%
  \makebox[#1]{\the\cytoks\unskip}%
}
\begin{document}
\spaceouttext{3pt plus 3pt}{This \textit{text \textbf{is} very} spaced
out}. Back to regular text.

\spaceouttext{1.5pt}{This \textit{text \textbf{is} somewhat} spaced
out}. Back to regular text.

\fbox{\spread{20em}{distribute \textit{this} text}}

\fbox{\spread{5em}{word}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for spending time on that, but I don't want to use any additional packages apart from `xparse`. I just need to modify the linked answer, but I don't know how.

Comment: @antshar I have never understood the imperative to avoid packages, but, of course, that is your call.