# latex3 — issues with cyrillic

Tags: expl3, latex3

For some reason the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Здравей

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {Здравей}
\tl_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 ~ }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

leads to bunch of errors

[image]

Looks like it's the problem with `\tl_map_inline`, since storing and using token list with cyrillic works fine.

---

Note that I'm using TeXLive 2022 while on 2019 it the code above works perfectly.

How can I fix the issues right now on 2022 setup?

Comment: using x-expansion on arbitrary text is never a good idea. Apart from this: utf8 chars are now protected. Use \tl_show:N\l_tmpa_tl to see the difference.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer or even `\show` :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle we german like long, posh command names without spaces ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Здравей

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {Здравей}
\show\l_tmpa_tl
\tl_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 ~ }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

You will see the current release defines

```
> \l_tmpa_tl=macro:
->Здравей.
```

older releases

```
> \l_tmpa_tl=macro:
->\T2A\CYRZ \T2A\cyrd \T2A\cyrr \T2A\cyra \T2A\cyrv \T2A\cyre \T2A\cyrishrt .
```

Usually the new version is to be preferred, what is the actual use case here, there is probably a way to achieve it?

---

A quick fix would be this which keeps each two-byte UTF-8 pair in a group:

```
> \l_tmpa_tl=macro:
->{З}{д}{р}{а}{в}{е}{й}.
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Здравей

\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\uviii#1#2{\ifx\relax#1\else{#1#2}\expandafter\uviii\fi}
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\uviii Здравей\relax\relax}
%\show\l_tmpa_tl
\tl_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 ~ }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Здравей

\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\uviii#1{\ifx\relax#1\else
\ifnum\expandafter`\string#1<128~
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\uviiia\else
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\uviiib
\fi
\fi
#1}
\def\uviiia#1{#1\uviii}
\def\uviiib#1#2{{#1#2}\uviii}
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\uviii Здравейabc\relax}
%\show\l_tmpa_tl
\tl_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 ~ }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: I consider this as a bug. Moreover, it seems like something goes wrong with the encoding when `expl3` parses cyrillic, like the packages for their support are ignored by `latex3`. Try to use `str` type instead of `tl` and it will work, but yield this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XWS2.png. I saw such random set of letter many times and it has always been caused by encoding problems.

Comment: The actual use cause is spreadlettering from my old [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543459/213149). Fortunately, another presented approach still works, so I will go with that, but the problem with `tl` really has to be fixed inside `latex3`.

Comment: @antshar it is not a bug so much as a change `\tl_map_inline:Nn` has _always_ iterated over pdftex tokens so would break multi-byte encodings such as utf-8. The fact that previously for that specific text you got one token per character after the `x`  expansion was  luck not design (not true in general, eg not for French or other accented latin, where this could never have workd previously) .

Comment: @antshar That said we will probably expose a new text_... version of the iterator that steps along utf-8 character  groups not tokens, which would be what you want here. (Such loops exist in the l3 upper/lower case code, but are not in a form callable from elsewhere currently)

Comment: In addition to mentioned issues, `\w` regex specifier for matching letters doesn't work either.

Comment: @antshar if you want utf8 chars to be "letters", use an unicode engine, with pdftex you will have to accept that they often consist of more than one byte and of commands.

Comment: Btw, your workaround with `\uviii` works with cyrillic **only**, so if text consist of latin letters, it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer why did someone even decide to give up that old construction with `\cyr•` in favor to actual unicode characters?

Comment: @antshar yes as I said, that version is specific to two-byte text, a full version would need to detect 1,2, 3 or 4 byte ranges, but not here. Your original version in older releases would essentially just work for a limited range of cyrillic as well.

Comment: the `\cyr...` commands are still used, to specify typesetting, but utf-8 is held as characters for longer, not least so you can have filenames or `\label`s with cyrillic where `Здравей` works but `\T2A\CYRZ \T2A\cyrd \T2A\cyrr \T2A\cyra \T2A\cyrv \T2A\cyre \T2A\cyrishrt` does not. @antshar

Comment: Is there anything I can temporary do now to make a quick fix for that and obtain the old behavior for both latin and cyrili letters?

Comment: @antshar added.

Comment: @antshar why the bug report???? As I explained the change is to introduce much more consistent handling of non latin letters, and your earlier code only worked by accident over a very limited set of letters. In earlier releases most characters would fail in an `x` argument and `tl_map` maps over tokens so would break any characters using more than one token. It happened  to work for the text in your example, but the new utf support is far more complete and consistent.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers cover why this is happening. It is likely that the team will add a 'text mapping' function soon - as a model for the present:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \text_map_function:nN #1#2
  { \exp_args:Ne \__text_map_function:nN { \text_expand:n {#1} } #2 }
\cs_new:Npn \__text_map_function:nN #1#2
  {
    \__text_map_function:Nw #2 #1
      \q__text_recursion_tail \q__text_recursion_stop
    \prg_break_point:Nn \text_map_break: { }
  }
\bool_lazy_or:nnTF
  { \sys_if_engine_luatex_p: }
  { \sys_if_engine_xetex_p: }
  {
    \cs_new:Npn \__text_map_function:Nw #1#2
      {
        \__text_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:Nn #2 { \text_map_break: }
        #1 {#2}
        \__text_map_function:Nw #1
      }
  }
  {
    \cs_new:Npn \__text_map_function:Nw #1#2
      {
        \__text_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:Nn #2 { \text_map_break: }
        \bool_lazy_and:nnTF
          { \tl_if_single_token_p:n {#2} }
          { ! \token_if_cs_p:N #2 }
          {
            \int_compare:nNnTF { `#2 } > { "80 }
              {
                \int_compare:nNnTF { `#2 } < { "E0 }
                  { \__text_map_function:NNN }
                  {
                     \int_compare:nNnTF { `#2 } < { "F0 }
                       { \__text_map_function:NNNN }
                       { \__text_map_function:NNNNN }
                  }
              }
              { \__text_map_function:Nn }
                #1 #2
          }
          { \__text_map_function:Nn #1 {#2} }
      }
    \cs_new:Npn \__text_map_function:NNN #1#2#3
      { \__text_map_function:Nn #1 {#2#3} }
    \cs_new:Npn \__text_map_function:NNNN #1#2#3#4
      { \__text_map_function:Nn #1 {#2#3#4} }
    \cs_new:Npn \__text_map_function:NNNNN #1#2#3#4#5
      { \__text_map_function:Nn #1 {#2#3#4#5} }
    \cs_new:Npn \__text_map_function:Nn #1#2
      {
        #1 {#2}
        \__text_map_function:Nw #1
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \text_map_break:
  { \prg_map_break:Nn \text_map_break: { } }
\cs_new:Npn \text_map_break:n
  { \prg_map_break:Nn \text_map_break: }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \text_map_inline:nn #1#2
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g__kernel_prg_map_int
    \cs_gset_protected:cpn
      { __text_map_ \int_use:N \g__kernel_prg_map_int :w } ##1 {#2}
    \exp_args:Nnc \text_map_function:nN {#1}
      { __text_map_ \int_use:N \g__kernel_prg_map_int :w }
    \prg_break_point:Nn \text_map_break:
      { \int_gdecr:N \g__kernel_prg_map_int }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\text_map_inline:nn { Здравей } { #1 ~ }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looking forward to seeing this function being shipped with `latex3`. Thank you for writing it down for my question.

Answer (score 1):

hyperref has to unprotect the utf8 chars locally to write the bookmarks. You can copy its code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter

 \def\antshar@expand@utfvii{%
    \count@"C2
    \@tempcnta"F5
    \def\UTFviii@tmp{\expandafter\def\expandafter~\expandafter{~}}%
    \UTFviii@loop
  }
  

\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin:
\antshar@expand@utfvii
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {Здравей}
\tl_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 ~ }
\group_end:

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks really neat! I keep delighting hyperref's clever solution that stays under the hood, but some of the approaches can actually be useful as standalone solution.