# Capitalize first letter of non-latin word (utf-8 two bits)

Tags: unicode, expl3, latex3, cyrillic, uppercase

There is plain `\uppercase` macro as well as `\MakeUppercase` in latex3. The last one works perfectly fine with two bits utf-8 characters as long as you explicitly brace the argument

```
\MakeUppercase{здравей}
```

Now I would like to capitalize the only the first letter of a word. Of course you can make it straight `\MakeUppercase{з}дравей` and it will work, however in the real use-case, the word is variable and stored in a macro:

```
\def\footext{здравей}
\expandafter\MakeUppercase\footext
```

And here the problem rise up that [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) greatly explained under this post: [latex3 — issues with cyrillic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/652860/213149).

Basically, because of that no command could grab first letter if not specified the argument explicitly:

```
\def\foo#1{#1}
\foo здарвей % error, the argument is only the first bit of 'з'
```

---

Is there a clever yet simple way of getting the desired result despite the text? So that it should support both one bit and two bit characters (even mixed).

---

Meanwhile I tried to create a bulk workaround, based on [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)'s solution of unprotecting utf-8 character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\def\expandutfvii{%
  \count@"C2
  \@tempcnta"F5
  \def\UTFviii@tmp{\expandafter\def\expandafter~\expandafter{~}}%
  \UTFviii@loop
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\expandutfvii
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {здравей}
\exp_last_unbraced:Nx \str_uppercase:n \l_tmpa_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

It almost works, but I couldn't *evaluate* the string so that it would use those commands instead of printing them
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\MakeTitlecase` (this requires a current LaTeX, the underlying expl3 command `\text_titlecase:n` can be used also in older systems).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\MakeUppercase{з}дравей 
   
\MakeTitlecase{здравей}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is this command from? It appears `undefined` on my TeXLive 2022 release.

Comment: it is in the current latex,

Comment: Here's the setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh6mT.png, but still `Undefined control sequence. \MakeTitlecase`

Comment: what matters is your LaTeX version. I have `LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5`

Comment: Just checked the [commits](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/3fc79b2e05da257b5fb1bb7a4ac7b94ec0a8ee65) and apparently the interface as a `\MakeTitlecase` macro has been added just a month ago. Looking up the changes, figured out the working way: `\text_titlecase:n {здравей}`

Comment: A bit off top, but may I wonder how you keep your setup always up-to-date? It takes more than an hour to install a new version of TeXLive for me (at least it was so when I upgraded from 2019).

Comment: I simply run `tlmgr update --all`. This updates the packages. And once a year I install a new texlive.

Comment: Worth noting that `\MakeTitlecase` does more than just ''uppercase the first codepoint'?

Comment: @antshar now you see the answer to [the question you asked earlier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652860/latex3-issues-with-cyrillic/652861#comment1627107_652861)  the change was to make this answer possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are using old 8bit TeX engine, no Unicoded engine in 2022. We have Unicode standard more than 20 years now an there is plenty fonts supporting it.

For example, when we use OpTeX (which is based on LuaTeX engine, supports Unicode) then there is no problem:

```
\fontfam[newcm]
\def\uppercasefirst#1{\uppercase{#1}}

\uppercasefirst здравей.

\bye
```

Comment: While it's easier in luatex, The problem was not that the user was using pdftex, rather that he was using an old latex without suitable support. Also as typical with latex, `\MakeTitlecase` does more than simple plain tex `#1` as you show here: it is doing locale sensitive titlecasing (which might mean `IJ` not `Ij` in dutch or keeping an accent in Greek even when `\MakeUppercase` drops accents as that is the specified behavour for Greek. (actually specifying the locale currently requires expl3, but that will change)