# Apply a macro to every word

Tags: macros

In order to improve the `\sameword` feature of reledmac, I would like to find a way to automatically apply a command to every word. For example, in plain TeX,

```
\def\foo#1{#1 (#1)}
foo bar foo bar foo bar foo, foo? foo. foo;
\end
```

should be automatically transformed to

```
\def\foo#1{#1 (#1)}
\foo{foo} \foo{bar} \foo{foo} \foo{bar} \foo{foo} \foo{bar} \foo{foo}, \foo{foo}? \foo{foo}. \foo{foo};
\end
```

My constraints are:

- excluding the punctuation mark
- excluding some commands (for example `foo\footnote{bar}` should become `\foo{foo}\footnote{bar}` and not `\foo{foo\footnote{bar}}`)
- if possible, working with pdfTeX, XeTeX and LuaTeX, but a LuaTeX-only solution would be nice.
- using any already existing LaTeX package (but a pure plainTeX is also accepted)

Comment: Your second constraint is the difficult one... how to exclude some/all macros.

Comment: yes, I know. Notes that the list of excluded macro could be defined manually.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253203/how-to-repeat-over-all-characters-in-a-string.  My answer there also shows how to do "something" to each word.  However, excluding macros would be an issue.

Comment: Your example caused my answer to fail!! finally realised it was the example that is wrong, plain tex `\footnote` takes (effectively) two arguments not one:-) see the usage in my update answer.

Comment: Just wondering whether preprocessing the source could be an alternative …? The script would only have to check for duplicate words that are max. 80 or so characters apart, so I'd imagine it wouldn't take too long to run.

Comment: @Florian: that is what I suggested to people who asked me. But the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh ! My bad. I will update my question

Comment: I wouldn't mind running an extra script, as long as I don't have to find all problematic words by hand. Such a script is still not trivial for non-programmers to write, so maybe a compromise would be to offer a ready-made script as part of the `reledmac`-distribution? Possibly with the option to let `reledmac` trigger it in a similar manner as e.g. `imakeidx` does for the index-processing? But _any_ automatisation of this problem would be very nice!

Comment: @why not. It should not be very difficult for me to write such script in python (indeed, I have already one). However it would be not possible to have the same feature as imakeidx, as it should run before the first run of LaTeX, in order to have a correct .tex input

Answer (score 14):

It would be *so* easy to break this, but..

[image]

```
\def\foo#1{#1 (#1)}
\def\xfoo#1 {%
\def\tmp{#1}%
\ifx\tmp\endfoo
\let\next\relax
\else
\ftnfoo#1\footnote\empty\empty\empty\relax
\let\next\xfoo
\fi
\next}
\def\ftnfoo#1\footnote#2#3#4\relax{%
\ifx\footnote#4\foo{#1}\footnote{#2}{#3} \else\afoo#1?\relax\fi}
\def\afoo#1?#2\relax{\ifx?#2\foo{#1}? \else\bfoo#1,\relax\fi}
\def\bfoo#1,#2\relax{\ifx,#2\foo{#1}, \else\cfoo#1;\relax\fi}
\def\cfoo#1;#2\relax{\ifx;#2\foo{#1}; \else\dfoo#1.\relax\fi}
\def\dfoo#1.#2\relax{\ifx.#2\foo{#1}. \else\foo{#1} \relax\fi}


\vsize=5\baselineskip

% assumes a space before the par
\def\yfoo#1\par{\xfoo#1!@ \par}

\def\endfoo{!@}

\yfoo
foo bar foo bar foo\footnote{$^1$}{bar} bar foo, foo? foo. foo;

\bye
```

Comment: updated with footnotes

Answer (score 10):

IMHO you need something like this:

```
\def\everyword#1#2{\let\domacro=#1\everywordA#2 {} }
\def\everywordA#1 {\ifx^#1^\else
   \def\tmp{}\everywordB #1\end
   \expandafter\everywordA \fi
}
\def\everywordB{\futurelet\next\everywordC}
\def\everywordC{\ifcat\noexpand\next A\expandafter\everywordD
                \else \expandafter\everywordE \fi}
\def\everywordD#1{\edef\tmp{\tmp#1}\everywordB}
\def\everywordE#1\end{\expandafter\domacro\expandafter{\tmp}#1}

\def\foo#1{#1 (#1)}
\everyword\foo{foo bar foo bar foo bar foo, foo? foo. foo;}
\end
```

The main idea of this macro is: we process each word separated by space first and each such word is divided to two parts: first the letter tokens (catcode 11) and second all tokens of another type.

Answer (score 9):

An implementation with `xparse` and the `l3regex` module of `expl3`; first the appearances of `\footnote` are kept out of the way, then in each piece runs of characters that are not spaces or punctuation are given as argument to a macro whose meaning can be set with `\setxsamewordformat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xsameword}{m}
 {
  \maieul_xsameword:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \maieul_xsameword:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl
   {
    \__maieul_xsameword_start:n { #1 }
   }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { (\c{footnote}\cB..*?\cE.) }
   { \cE\} \1 \c{__maieul_xsameword_start:n} \cB\{ }
   \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__maieul_xsameword_start:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { ([^\s,.!?]+) }
   { \c{maieul_xsameword_format:n} \cB\{ \1 \cE\} }
   \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\setxsamewordformat}{m}
 {
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \maieul_xsameword_format:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setxsamewordformat{#1 (#1)}

\textheight=3cm

\begin{document}

\xsameword{foo \textit{bar} baz? foo\footnote{footnote footnote} bar}

\setxsamewordformat{\textbf{#1}}

\xsameword{foo \textit{bar} baz? foo\footnote{footnote footnote} bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that also non ASCII characters are managed.

Comment: I think your answer, as based on regexp, is the better one. I will look on it more carefuly later.

Comment: @Maïeul There are limitations, of course: something like `\textit{foo\footnote{bar}}` is not going to work. Also efficiency is out of the question, I'm afraid. More testing with real use cases would be needed to fine tune it. The list of “exceptions” can be extended.

Comment: yes of course. For now, I have to understand your code well.

Comment: however, maybe the solution proposed by @florian will be the best one: using external script.

Comment: `\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}` dont work, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479650/l3regex-sty-not-found#comment1292576_479650

Comment: @AndréC Thanks, removed.