# How to have the start of each word in a heading be colored?

Tags: sectioning, color

So I'm making a CV and I want the first three letters of each word in a heading to be colored, at the moment it just colors the first three letters of the first word in the heading.

So basically I have a hobbies & interests section, I want the first three letters of `HOBbies & INTerests` to be colored but no the `&` symbol.

Anyone know what I need to add in order to color the second word in the heading? I played around with it but I honestly don't know much about this.

```
\RequirePackage{parskip}

\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        blue\or%
        red\or%
        orange\or%
        green\or%
        purple\or%
        red\or%
        aquamarine\else%
        headercolor\fi%
    } #1#2#3%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  {\par\vspace{\parskip}
  {%
    \LARGE\headingfont\color{headercolor}%
    \@sectioncolor #1%
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}}
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[2]{
  \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
  \Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} #2%
  \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
}

\newcommand{\jobtitle}[1]{%
    {\color{gray}\bodyfontit #1}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Can you place a minimal code that shows the 'HOBbies & INTerests' sections before being colored?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280967/apply-a-macro-to-every-word