# Is there an incompatibility between the new version 2021 of babel and Latex 3?

Tags: babel, latex3

Indeed, the following macro `\NewDocumentCommand{\xsameword}{m}` written by @nox in his [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442654/138900), has a compile-time error.

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   :
l.74 \end{frame}
```

An excerpt from the log (which I hope is well chosen) with the LaTeX3 command  `\errorcontextlines=5` as requested by @DonHosek

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   :
\l__regex_internal_a_tl ...word_format\exp_not:N :
                                                  n\cs_end: \exp_after:wN {\...
<argument> ...}\fi: }\fi: \l__regex_internal_a_tl 
                                                  \if_int_compare:w \l__rege...

\use:x ...cs_set_nopar:Npx \l__exp_internal_tl {#1
                                                  }\l__exp_internal_tl 
\__maieul_xsameword_start:n ..._xsameword_list_tl 
                                                  \tl_use:N \l__maieul_xsame...

\beamer@doifinframe ...té d'aire est appelée le}
                                                   \keepword {\og \textit {\...
...
l.74 \end{frame}
                
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   :
\l__regex_internal_a_tl ...word_format\exp_not:N :
                                                  n\cs_end: \exp_after:wN {\...
<argument> ...}\fi: }\fi: \l__regex_internal_a_tl 
                                                  \if_int_compare:w \l__rege...

\use:x ...cs_set_nopar:Npx \l__exp_internal_tl {#1
                                                  }\l__exp_internal_tl 
\__maieul_xsameword_start:n ..._xsameword_list_tl 
                                                  \tl_use:N \l__maieul_xsame...

\beamer@doifinframe ...té d'aire est appelée le}
                                                   \keepword {\og \textit {\...
```

When the babel package is **not loaded**, there are no **more errors**.

1. What is the problem?
2. And how to solve it ?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

% from egreg's answer at
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280981/97512
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xsameword}{m}
{
  \leavevmode\maieul_xsameword:n { #1 }
}

\tl_new:N \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \maieul_xsameword:n
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl
  {
    \__maieul_xsameword_start:n { #1 }
  }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
  { (\c{footnote}\cB..*?\cE.) }
  { \cE\} \1 \c{__maieul_xsameword_start:n} \cB\{ }
  \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__maieul_xsameword_start:n
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
  { ([^\s,.!?]+) }% Delete what should not be printed again here
  { \c{maieul_xsameword_format:n} \cB\{ \1 \cE\} }
  \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\setxsamewordformat}{m}
{
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \maieul_xsameword_format:n { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newbox\mytmpbox

\newcommand{\repword}[1]{%
  \sbox{\mytmpbox}{#1}%
  \hbox to \wd\mytmpbox{\hss\hspace{.2em}''\hss}%
}

\setxsamewordformat{\repword{#1}}

\newcommand{\keepword}[2]{%
  \sbox{\mytmpbox}{#2}%
  \hbox to \wd\mytmpbox{\hss#1\hss}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

Lorsque le \og \textit{carreau carré} \fg{}   mesure:
\begin{itemize}
  \item {1}\,$cm$ de côté, l'unité d'aire est appelée le \og \textit{\textrm{centimètre carré}} \fg{} et est noté $cm^2$;

  \item 1\,\keepword{$dm$}{$cm$} \xsameword{de côté, l'unité d'aire est appelée le} \keepword{\og \textit{\textrm{décimètre carré}} \fg{}}{\og \textit{\textrm{centimètre carré}} \fg{}} \xsameword{et est noté} $cm^2$;

  \item 1\,\keepword{$m$}{$cm$} \xsameword{de côté, l'unité d'aire est appelée le}  \keepword{\og \textit{\textrm{mètre carré}} \fg{}}{\og \textit{\textrm{centimètre carré}} \fg{}} \xsameword{et est noté} \keepword{$m^2$}{$cm^2$};
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It runs fine on my system. I have `2021/04/26 3.58 The Babel package`—perhaps you're out of date since this is just two weeks old?

Comment: I have the MikTeX latest version `Package: babel 2021/04/26 3.58 The Babel package`

Comment: @davidcarlilse say it dont work on chat [TeX, LaTeX and Friends](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57944558#57944558)

Comment: Something must be out of date. Does MikTeX provide a means to update everything to the latest version?

Comment: Did you see my last message ?

Comment: I did. IIRC David uses MikTeX too. I'm on TeXlive

Comment: Try adding `\errorcontextlines=5` to you file to get more context for the error.

Comment: The log file is available [here](https://cjoint.com/c/KElficMKkNg)

Comment: Please put the log into your  question, we generally do not like to go to random sites to get relevant information. Additionally links rot over time

Comment: The example compiled fine for me on MikTeX before I applied the 2021-05-08/2021-05-09 updates. After applying the updates (amongst them `l3kernel` and other LaTeX3 components, the other packages seem irrelevant: `latex-dev` components, `latexmk`, the smybols list, `biblatex` styles) I also get the errors.

Comment: I reported it yesterday https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/909 and Bruno fixed it already.

Comment: @daleif The log is too big and refused by the site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a bug. I reported it yesterday and it has been fixed in the sources.

https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/909