# OpenType 'rand' (Randomize) feature not correct implemented in XeTeX?

Tags: xetex, luatex, opentype, random

If XeLaTeX (v3.14159265-2.6-0.99996) compiles

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont[Letters=Random]{punknova-regular.otf}
\begin{document}
bananes et ananas
\end{document}
```

it will output a document with just one fixed variant per glyph (every "a" is the same picture):

[image: Random variants are fixed variants]

Omitting `Letters=Random` shows that XeLaTeX indeed is able to use variants but is not able to pick them randomly:

[image: No variant glyphs]

In contrast, LuaLaTeX compiles the same document correctly:

[image: LuaLaTeX can handle the Randomize feature]

The question is, whether this is a bug in XeLaTeX or if there is a possibility to force XeLaTeX cycling through the random variants (e.g. by adding an option to fontspec)?

Comment: an old 2011 harbuzz message, it was not implemented at that point it seems https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/harfbuzz/2011-June/001308.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think `+rand` is supported however   you can access all the variants by name (`a.1` to `a.31` in the case of "a") and then randomise in TeX eg using the PGF `random` function.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont[Letters=Random]{punknova-regular.otf}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}


\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a"
\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.1"
\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.2"
\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.3"
\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.4"
\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.5"
\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.6"


\pgfmathparse{random(31)}\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.\pgfmathresult"
\pgfmathparse{random(31)}\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.\pgfmathresult"
\pgfmathparse{random(31)}\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.\pgfmathresult"
\pgfmathparse{random(31)}\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.\pgfmathresult"
\pgfmathparse{random(31)}\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.\pgfmathresult"
\pgfmathparse{random(31)}\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.\pgfmathresult"
\pgfmathparse{random(31)}\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.\pgfmathresult"
\pgfmathparse{random(31)}\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.\pgfmathresult"
\pgfmathparse{random(31)}\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.\pgfmathresult"
\pgfmathparse{random(31)}\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.\pgfmathresult"
\pgfmathparse{random(31)}\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "a.\pgfmathresult"

\end{document}
```

---

Putting it all together, you can make a table with the glyph names and number of variants and then:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\pntable#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\def\csname pn\number"#1-name\endcsname{#2}%
  \expandafter\def\csname pn\number"#1-max\endcsname{#3}%
}
\pntable{0021}{exclam}{7}
\pntable{0022}{quotedbl}{7}
\pntable{0023}{numbersign}{7}
\pntable{0024}{dollar}{7}
\pntable{0025}{percent}{7}
\pntable{0026}{ampersand}{7}
\pntable{0027}{quotesingle}{7}
\pntable{0028}{parenleft}{7}
\pntable{0029}{parenright}{7}
\pntable{002A}{asterisk}{7}
\pntable{002B}{plus}{7}
\pntable{002C}{comma}{7}
\pntable{002D}{hyphen}{7}
\pntable{002E}{period}{7}
\pntable{002F}{slash}{7}
\pntable{0030}{zero}{7}
\pntable{0031}{one}{7}
\pntable{0032}{two}{7}
\pntable{0033}{three}{7}
\pntable{0034}{four}{7}
\pntable{0035}{five}{7}
\pntable{0036}{six}{7}
\pntable{0037}{seven}{7}
\pntable{0038}{eight}{7}
\pntable{0039}{nine}{7}
\pntable{003A}{colon}{7}
\pntable{003B}{semicolon}{7}
\pntable{003C}{less}{7}
\pntable{003D}{equal}{7}
\pntable{003E}{greater}{7}
\pntable{003F}{question}{7}
\pntable{0040}{at}{7}
\pntable{0041}{A}{15}
\pntable{0042}{B}{15}
\pntable{0043}{C}{15}
\pntable{0044}{D}{15}
\pntable{0045}{E}{15}
\pntable{0046}{F}{15}
\pntable{0047}{G}{15}
\pntable{0048}{H}{15}
\pntable{0049}{I}{15}
\pntable{004A}{J}{15}
\pntable{004B}{K}{15}
\pntable{004C}{L}{15}
\pntable{004D}{M}{15}
\pntable{004E}{N}{15}
\pntable{004F}{O}{15}
\pntable{0050}{P}{15}
\pntable{0051}{Q}{15}
\pntable{0052}{R}{15}
\pntable{0053}{S}{15}
\pntable{0054}{T}{15}
\pntable{0055}{U}{15}
\pntable{0056}{V}{15}
\pntable{0057}{W}{15}
\pntable{0058}{X}{15}
\pntable{0059}{Y}{15}
\pntable{005A}{Z}{15}
\pntable{005B}{bracketleft}{7}
\pntable{005C}{backslash}{7}
\pntable{005D}{bracketright}{7}
\pntable{005E}{asciicircum}{7}
\pntable{005F}{underscore}{7}
\pntable{0060}{grave}{7}
\pntable{0061}{a}{31}
\pntable{0062}{b}{31}
\pntable{0063}{c}{31}
\pntable{0064}{d}{31}
\pntable{0065}{e}{31}
\pntable{0066}{f}{31}
\pntable{0067}{g}{31}
\pntable{0068}{h}{31}
\pntable{0069}{i}{31}
\pntable{006A}{j}{31}
\pntable{006B}{k}{31}
\pntable{006C}{l}{31}
\pntable{006D}{m}{31}
\pntable{006E}{n}{31}
\pntable{006F}{o}{31}
\pntable{0070}{p}{31}
\pntable{0071}{q}{31}
\pntable{0072}{r}{31}
\pntable{0073}{s}{31}
\pntable{0074}{t}{31}
\pntable{0075}{u}{31}
\pntable{0076}{v}{31}
\pntable{0077}{w}{31}
\pntable{0078}{x}{31}
\pntable{0079}{y}{31}
\pntable{007A}{z}{31}
\pntable{007B}{braceleft}{7}
\pntable{007D}{braceright}{7}
\pntable{00A1}{exclamdown}{7}
\pntable{00A8}{dieresis}{7}
\pntable{00AF}{macron}{7}
\pntable{00B4}{acute}{7}
\pntable{00B8}{cedilla}{7}
\pntable{00BF}{questiondown}{7}
\pntable{00C6}{AE}{15}
\pntable{00D8}{Oslash}{15}
\pntable{00DF}{germandbls}{31}
\pntable{00E6}{ae}{31}
\pntable{00F8}{oslash}{31}
\pntable{0131}{dotlessi}{31}
\pntable{0152}{OE}{15}
\pntable{0153}{oe}{31}
\pntable{0237}{uni0237}{31} %dotlessj
\pntable{02C6}{circumflex}{7}
\pntable{02C7}{caron}{7}
\pntable{02D8}{breve}{7}
\pntable{02D9}{dotaccent}{7}
\pntable{02DA}{ring}{7}
\pntable{02DC}{tilde}{7}
\pntable{02DD}{hungarumlaut}{7}
\pntable{0391}{Alpha}{15}
\pntable{0392}{Beta}{15}
\pntable{0393}{Gamma}{15}
\pntable{0394}{Delta}{15}
\pntable{0395}{Epsilon}{15}
\pntable{0396}{Zeta}{15}
\pntable{0397}{Eta}{15}
\pntable{0398}{Theta}{15}
\pntable{0399}{Iota}{15}
\pntable{039A}{Kappa}{15}
\pntable{039B}{Lambda}{15}
\pntable{039C}{Mu}{15}
\pntable{039D}{Nu}{15}
\pntable{039E}{Xi}{15}
\pntable{039F}{Omicron}{15}
\pntable{03A0}{Pi}{15}
\pntable{03A1}{Rho}{15}
\pntable{03A3}{Sigma}{15}
\pntable{03A4}{Tau}{15}
\pntable{03A5}{Upsilon}{15}
\pntable{03A6}{Phi}{15}
\pntable{03A7}{Chi}{15}
\pntable{03A8}{Psi}{15}
\pntable{03A9}{Omega}{15}
\pntable{2013}{endash}{7}
\pntable{2014}{emdash}{7}
\pntable{2018}{quoteleft}{7}
\pntable{2019}{quoteright}{7}
\pntable{201C}{quotedblleft}{7}
\pntable{201D}{quotedblright}{7}

\makeatletter

\def\rndpn#1{\xrndpn#1\relax}

\def\xrndpn#1{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\else
\expandafter\ifx\csname pn\number\expandafter`\noexpand#1-name\endcsname\relax
#1%
\else
\pgfmathrandominteger\pgfmathresult
  {1}%
  {\csname pn\number\expandafter`\string#1-max\endcsname}%
\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex 
  "\csname pn\number\expandafter`\string#1-name\endcsname.\pgfmathresult"\relax
\fi
\expandafter\xrndpn
\fi}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont[Letters=Random]{punknova-regular.otf}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

\rndpn{bananes\ et\ ananas}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great to see the TeX using modern font technology out-of-the-box!

Comment: I have reported this HarfBuzz bug [here](https://github.com/behdad/harfbuzz/issues/427). The workaround of  David Carlisle may be useful for a specific Punk Nova package but depends on the font. I thank you anyway, David.

Comment: @LinusRomer sure, the numbers depend on the font but the general approach would work for any font, so might be usable until harfbuzz suports this (and xetex uses that version), you just need to use fontforge or similar to extract list of variants.

Comment: You can also use `rand=0` to `rand=31` as font features and avoid hard-coding glyph names.

Comment: @KhaledHosny Hi nice to see you here!  I'm sure the above isn't the best possible interface I was just playing to see if I could get something working.  I'm not sure I know exactly how that translates to a fontspec interface (Perhaps I'll ask Will to translate:-) Or you could post an answer as well?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If the random glyphs are in the Private Use Area, your approach has to be generalized (I think). Undoubtedly, the idea stays the same: Read the tables of the Randomize feature, choose random indices and take the letter with the corresponding index. Of course I am happy, if somebody implements it in XeTeX.

Comment: @LinusRomer in this case I'm accessing the glyphs via the glyph index, so they don't need to be encoded in the PUA or anywhere else, but yes each font may put them somewhere different, for this one font I just translated the tables by hand from fontforge display to tex markup, but that isn't a general service, although I would guess there are not so many fonts with this feature so one package per such font wouldn't be impossible, even if the package has to be coded by hand,

Answer (score 5):

This is expanding on David Carlisle’s answer. Instead of using glyph names, we can treat `rand` feature as a simple multiple alternate feature and try to access those alternates randomly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{punknova-regular.otf}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\randomalt#1{%
 \pgfmathparse{random(31)}%
 {\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+rand=\pgfmathresult}}#1}%
}
\def\randomtext#1{\@tfor\next:=#1\do{\randomalt{\next}}}
\makeatother

% XXX: the spaces are eaten by the loop unless escaped!
\randomtext{bananes\ et\ ananas}

\end{document}
```

[image: XeTeX output]

There are some caveats, though:

- Due to the way `\addfontfeature{}` is implemented, font features between the characters will not work (kerning, ligatures, etc.) since each alternate will be using a different font. This is not an issue for Punk Nova though as it does not have any such features IIRC.
- There is currently no way to get the number of alternates supported by the feature (the `31` above), one will need to examine the font externally or just use an arbitrary number.
- The spaces need to be escaped in the macro above, but that is probably because of my poor TeX skills (I just copied the macro from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253205/729).

---

A version that doesn't need to escape spaces

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 

\newfontfamily{\punk}{punknova-regular.otf}
\usepackage{pgf}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\randomtext}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \punk
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_khaled_randomtext_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_khaled_randomtext_seq
   {
    \khaled_random_word:n { ##1 }~
   }
   \unskip % remove the last space
   \group_end:
 }

\seq_new:N \l_khaled_randomtext_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \khaled_random_word:n
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \group_begin:
    \pgfmathparse{random(31)}
    \addfontfeature{RawFeature={+rand=\pgfmathresult}}##1
    \group_end:
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Normal text

\randomtext{bananes et ananas}

Normal text

\end{document}
```

[image]